# react native moment updateLocal fr crush android

Tags: android, react-native, build, momentjs, expo

I want to translate date to french language using moment library.

I create an android build but it crashed when i open the component.

My code is :

```
import Moment from 'moment';

// i fixed the error 
// var moment = require('moment');
//require('moment/locale/fr');
//moment.locale('fr');



    render() {
....
{
this.state.notifications.map((notification, i) => (     
    Moment.updateLocale('fr', {
        // the config here
        // translate to french
    }),
    notification.type === 'Partage de contact' ?
        <ListItem
            key={i}
            ...
            subtitle={`Date : ${Moment(notification.date).format('dddd D MMMM,  YYYY')}`}
            bottomDivider
        />
        :
        <ListItem
            ...
            subtitle={`Date : ${Moment(notification.date).format('dddd D MMMM,  YYYY')}`}
            bottomDivider
        />
))
}
...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate date to any(french) language using `moment.local()`

```
import moment from 'moment';


render() {

  var march = moment('2017-03')

  console.log(march.format('MMMM')) 

  moment.locale('fr') // you can set here 

  console.log(march.format('MMMM'))

  ................

}
```

Comment: I use moment.local('fr') but i got an english date

Comment: are you sure try to log

Comment: I fixed using this : var moment = require('moment');
require('moment/locale/fr');
moment.locale('fr');

Comment: great job keep it up